# how can do vector of list referring to the value in list?

Tags: c++, list, vector

How can I make vector of lists referring to value in list by pointer without `pop` (`delete`)?
`vec[I].j` must refer to value in list in the vector (`vec`)
    but  `vec[i].j`  didn't work

```
vector<list<int>>vec;

for (auto j = vec[i].begin(); j != vec[i].end(); j++)
    for (auto h = map.begin(); h !=map.end(); ++h)              
        if (vec[i].j == h->first)
            f = false;
```

Comment: Fix the formatting of your code, and the dozens of typos in your post so we can try to understand your question. Also `Java` and `C++` are two different languages. Pick one.

Comment: **-1**, please clarify your question, I can't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (vec[i].j == h->first)
```

should be rewritten as

```
if (*j == h->first)
```